# Do I need an nginx server in front of gunicorn on my backend VM if I use a GCP load balancer?

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

Details:
Using GCP load balancer (not sure which one yet)
Have gunicorn/uvicorn server setup on backend VMs for FastAPI
Debating whether I need nginx in front of the gunicorn server
No static content to serve; I'm mostly worried about buffering slow clients

Comment: Do you need Nginx in your example - no. Should you - yes. Only trust hardened web servers such as Apache, Nginx, IIS, etc for front-facing web services.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to go down this route :)